# (Tomcat) Web service : OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Tags: multithreading, web-services, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jvm

I am creating a web service that creates a huge amount of small java timer threads over (10k). I can only seem to create 2k timer threads before I get the OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread. How do i solve this? I am using a macbook pro to run my Tomcat server on. I'v configured the ulimit (-u) max user processes to double what it used to be but I still get the same problem. What are my options, if any, to make this doable?

Comment: I would suggest rethinking your approach and considering whether you really need to model this with threads. Even if you can configure it correctly, I'd question whether threads were the correct approach for this.

Answer (score 5):

It's often a *bad idea* for web applications to start their own (few) threads, let alone 10K threads - and then "as timers"? Seriously? Don't go there.

What can you do?

- Don't rely on the ability to create those threads.
- Change your architecture! Use a scheduler library that has solved this problem already (e.g. [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org) or others).
- If you don't want to use an external library (why wouldn't you?): Implement a single timer thread that executes the scheduled operations when they're due. *Do not* use a new thread for each scheduled operation

If you wanted to boil 100 eggs, would you buy 100 timers?